# Unable to connect Azure SQL database from Python using Key Vault Secret

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc, azure-keyvault

My Key vault secret is

```
integrated security=False;encrypt=True;connection timeout=30;data source=yyy.database.windows.net;initial catalog=db-xxxx;user id=xx-user;password=pwd-xx
```

I am able to connect to Azure SQL database using the above KV secret from Azure ADF.
I am trying to do the same thru Python code:

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import pyodbc

KVUri = "https://yyy-kv.vault.azure.net/"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)
secretName = "xxxx"
print("Retrieving your secret")
retrieved_secret = client.get_secret(secretName)
print(f"Your secret is '{retrieved_secret.value}'.")
print(" done.")
# The code fails after this.
with pyodbc.connect(retrieved_secret.value) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 3 name, collation_name FROM sys.databases")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```

But the code fails with the below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 25, in <module>
    with pyodbc.connect(retrieved_secret.value) as conn:
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Can you help me what changes I have to do in KV or still Azure does not support Python KV? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You connection string should be like below.

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=yy.database.windows.net,1433;Database=dbname;Uid=sasasa;Pwd={pwd};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;
```

*I believe if you change the secret  in kv, you can fix the issue.*

**Offical doc:**

[Connect SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15#connect)

Comment: Thanks Jason. I am aware about the connection string. I am trying to connect to Azure SQL using Azure Key Vault secret.